# How do I apply the dct values to the formula?

Tags: algorithm, face-detection

I am implementing an algorithm about face detection corresponding to a paper i have found. At the end of the paper it uses the dct values to take out false alarms by using some formulas. One of them is the following: 
 [image]

My question is: I have calculated dct values for MxN, now how do i apply them to the formula?

**EDIT:** So that is what you mean? (The 0 to 7 inner loops are a random part of the 100x100 dct1 array, which has only y dct, the cb,cr are not needed for the algorith)

```
for(i = 0; i <= M * N * (4 - 1); i++){
        for(m = 0; m <= 7; m++){
            for(n = 0; n <= 7; n++){
                value += std::pow(dct1.at<float>(m,n),2);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Following the formula, take the sum of the 8 x 8 DCT coefficients squared, and sum for all macroblocks.

Comment: So if i have a 100 x 100 face region i take just the first 8 x 8 dct (or any other random 8x8 ) and then sum them for all macroblocks and it is correct?

Comment: You sum all macroblocks of all types.

Comment: If you write the answer, i'll happily give the check mark.

Comment: `test1=15` is a bit confusing.

Comment: My fault it was just test related :)